# ffmpeg concat with safe 0 don't work if another list is included

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two files like,

`file1.txt`

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 'video1.mp4'
file 'file2.txt'
```

and `file2.txt`

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 'video2.mp4'
file 'file1.txt'
```

I am using `ffmpeg -nostdin -re -f concat -safe 0 -i ./file1.txt -c copy ...`.

It works for first file `file1.txt` then when loop to `file2.txt`, it gives error like

> Unsafe file name video2.mp4 ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have got a way to figure it out: Just generate the txt file to the path where between the video/clip files like that:

[txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SWJH.png)

[txt detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGA6p.png)

And run the ffmpeg script with file path:

ffmpeg -nostdin -re -f concat -safe 0 -i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\file1.txt -c copy ....

It works~